# Looking for weird fantasy graphic novel

Tags: story-identification, graphic-novel

I read this graphic novel about four to five years ago.

It has traveling between worlds, I think. Maybe the ghost and the human world? But I don't know - I do know that the character met his grandfather and can fly. There's a lot of other magic, like changing sizes and maybe teleportation.

A bunch of other random facts from the story:

- They ate spiders
- The characters in the (maybe) ghost world aren't really human
- Time/world travel ship created by a women
- The people sent to fetch the main character were in a relationship
- There was an evil dude who used this weird machine that produced green light to determine the main character's potential

Is there any fantasy graphic novel that fits this description?

Comment: Please tell me if I should add extra information.

Comment: You should add absolutely everything you remember; you never know what detail will trigger someone's memory.

Comment: @DavidW I will try, but at the moment, I believe this is all I remember.

Comment: Was the graphic novel in English or another language? Was it in color or B&W? How would you describe the art style? Was it tpb format, manga format or larger (like Euro-comics)?

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen It was English, but not manga style. There was color . . . and I don't really know about the style. It was kind of crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found it.

A page-turning adventure of a boy's journey to the land of ghosts and back.

Imagine Garth Hale's surprise when he's accidentally zapped to the spirit world by Frank Gallows, a washed-out ghost wrangler. Suddenly Garth finds he has powers the ghosts don't have, and he's stuck in a world run by the evil ruler of Ghostopolis, who would use Garth's newfound abilities to rule the ghostly kingdom. When Garth meets Cecil, his grandfather's ghost, the two search for a way to get Garth back home, and nearly lose hope until Frank Gallows shows up to fix his mistake.

[image: Ghostopolis]